# How to add new line in a file

Tags: ruby

I want to add newline character below.
But the result is wrong.
Teach me what is wrong.

test.txt(before)

```
------------------
2014-09
2014-10
2014-11
------------------
```

test.txt(after)

```
------------------
2014-09
2014-10

2014-11
------------------
```

I make a ruby script below, but the result is wrong.

```
f = File.open("test.txt","r+")
f.each{|line|
  if line.include?("2014-10")
    f.puts nil 
  end
}
f.close
```

the result

```
------------------
2014-09
2014-10

014-11
------------------
```

Comment: check this http://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex16.html

Comment: Instead of `f.puts` try `f.write "\n"`

Comment: @takuma - could you put expected o/p here?

Comment: You are overwriting the character `2` with `nil`. It may seem like a lot of work to add just one character, but it's easiest to create a new file. You can do this in one of two ways. You could read the entire file into a string, close the file, modify the string in memory and write the string to a file with the same name, overwriting the original file. The second way is to read each line of the file into a string, modify the string and write the modified string to a file with a different name. When you are finished, close both files, delete the first and rename the second to the old filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading and writing a file at the same time can get messy, same thing with other data structures like arrays. You should build a new file as you go along.

Some notes:

- you should use the block form of `File.open` because it will stop you from forgetting to call `f.close`
- `puts nil` is the same as `puts` without arguments
- single quotes are preferred over double quotes when you don’t need string interpolation
- you should use `do ... end` instead of `{ ... }` for multi-line blocks
- `File.open(...).each` can be replaced with `File.foreach`
- the intermediate result can be stored in a `StringIO` object which will respond to `puts` etc.

Example:

```
require 'stringio'

file = 'test.txt'
output = StringIO.new

File.foreach(file) do |line|
  if line.include? '2014-10'
    output.puts
  else
    output << line
  end
end

output.rewind

File.open(file, 'w') do |f|
  f.write output.read
end
```

Answer (score 2):

To solve your problem, the easiest way is to create a new file to output your new text into. To do you'll need to open the input file and the output file and iterate each line of the file check the condition and put desired line into the output file.

Example

```
require 'fileutils'

File.open("text-output.txt", "w") do |output|
  File.foreach("text.txt") do |line|
    if line.include?("2014-10")
      output.puts line + "\n"
    else
      output.puts line
    end
  end
end

FileUtils.mv("text-output.txt", "text.txt")
```

Easy way

```
File.write(f = "text.txt", File.read(f).gsub(/2014-10/,"2014-10\n"))
```